# Breaking out of string in javaScript css declaration?

Tags: javascript

Sorry for the weak title.

I have some jQuery that is going pretty well, however, I guess I don't know some of the basics. I want to write -wt/2px as the left margin but I don't understand how it's breaking out between string and number - any help?

Here is what we came up with after the answer / (we were over-riding our own css was just one of the problems [CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/nouveau/pen/pLACg)

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  var innerH = $('.v-align'),
    ht = innerH.height();

  var innerW = $('.h-align'),
    wt = innerW.width();

  innerH.css({
    'position':'absolute',
    'top':'50%',
    'margin':-ht/2+'px 0 0 0'
  });

  innerW.css({
    'position':'absolute',
    'left':'50%',
    // ?
    'margin': '0 0 0 '+(-wt/2)+'px'
  });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use parens when in doubt:

```
 innerH.css({
    'position':'absolute',
    'top':'50%',
    'margin': (-ht/2)+'px 0 0 0'
  });

  innerW.css({
    'position':'absolute',
    'left':'50%',
   'margin': '0 0 0 '+(-wt/2)+'px'
  });
```

Comment: I'm not having problems with margin-top, I'm having problems understanding how to write margin-left. See the /* ? */

Comment: I want to write something like: 'margin': '0 0 0 (-wt/2)px'

Comment: Well, I think you answered my question. As usual, I ended up with more questions. How do the +'s work? The centering based on container width is working, but the offset margin for the top is not. Gonna mark this answered, but if you want to look at that fiddle that would be cool. Thanks. dw c/o nouveau

Comment: Actually, ignore that fiddle... this whole things has gone wrong. Your answer was correct though. I am just going about this all wrong. Thanks again. dw c/o nouveau

Comment: @nouveau: the "+" concats strings as well as performs addition. when you have mixed strings and numbers, it can be ambiguous which operation should be performed, but parens make it explicit.

Comment: Thanks. By the way, I'm over-riding my margins, by putting both classes on the div. Silly me.